# Using FileSystemObject in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-office

I'm using Access 2010, and here is screenshot from my reference libraries and avalible FileSystemObject methods from within Access VB IDE:

[image]

---

When I initiate this object I can't seem to be able to access familiar methods, as I get exception with this example debug result:

[image]

---

I also used explicit declarations and initialized variables to get same results.

Any ideas what may be wrong?

---

To replay on @4dmonster comment, this is the actual array:

```
For Each p In Split("f:\temp\test\op1\gev_final_1.xlsx;f:\temp\test\op1\gev_final_2.xlsx;f:\temp\test\op1\gev_final_3.xlsx;f:\temp\test\op1\gev_final_4.xlsx;" & _
                     "f:\temp\test\op1\gev_final_5.xlsx;f:\temp\test\op1\gev_final_6.xlsx;f:\temp\test\op1\gev_final_7.xlsx;f:\temp\test\op2\gev_final_8.xlsx;" & _
                     "f:\temp\test\op2\gev_final_9.xlsx;f:\temp\test\op2\gev_final_10.xlsx;f:\temp\test\op2\gev_final_11.xlsx;f:\temp\test\op2\gev_final_12.xlsx;" & _
                     "f:\temp\test\op2\gev_final_13.xlsx;f:\temp\test\op3\gev_final_14.xlsx;f:\temp\test\op3\gev_final_15.xlsx;f:\temp\test\op3\gev_final_16.xlsx;" & _
                     "f:\temp\test\op3\gev_final_17.xlsx;f:\temp\test\op3\gev_final_18.xlsx;f:\temp\test\op3\gev_final_19.xlsx;f:\temp\test\op4\gev_final_20.xlsx;" & _
                     "f:\temp\test\op4\gev_final_21.xlsx;f:\temp\test\op4\gev_final_22.xlsx;f:\temp\test\op4\gev_final_23.xlsx;f:\temp\test\op4\gev_final_24.xlsx;" & _
                     "f:\temp\test\op5\gev_final_25.xlsx;f:\temp\test\op5\gev_final_26.xlsx;f:\temp\test\op5\gev_final_27.xlsx", ";")
```

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: It says "Path is not valid", although file exists. I now tested the code as VBS, and also WSH reports the same error. But if I print `p` variable and put the string in Windows run dialog file is opened as expected. The drive is USB, but that shouldn't matter...

Comment: show us full path in p

Comment: I upadted the question with actual array, and will hopefully track this as I didn't expected same problem to arise with VBS. Thanks

Comment: Could it be that you are passing "f:\temp\test\op1\gev_final_1.xlsx" to `GetFolder()` and `GetFolder()` is complaining because there is no *folder* with that name? (Assuming that "f:\temp\test\op1\gev_final_1.xlsx" is actually a *file*....)

Comment: That's it, thanks. I thought that `GetFolder` expects full path and returns it's folder. Sorry for this noise...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `GetFolder()` is being passed a string containing the full path to a *file* and it is rightfully complaining that such a *folder* does not exist. If you want to extract the *folder* in which a particular *file* resides then you could use something like

```
fso.GetFile("C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb").ParentFolder
```